# MDN example (of Math.random()): could it be parseInt() instead of Math.floor()?

Tags: javascript, math, random

I was reading a JavaScript tutorial and searching for functions on MDN website when I stumbled across this example of `Math.random()`:

```
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

While I understand that `Math.floor` chooses the biggest number and with that erases all numbers that have decimal values, I already learnt another function called `parseInt()` which just deletes all of the numbers after point. So, what's the difference between those two? Couldn't I just use

```
function getRandomInclusive(min, max) {
return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

instead?
I got idea while writing this question that `Math.floor()` might write 5 when it's 4,5 and `parseInt()` would write 4, but it's not really important for random number generator as I understand (if you know any examples of when it would be important, please tell me!) So, there's still not much of a difference in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseInt` parses a *string* into an integer, reading only digits at the beginning of that string. It is not appropriate to use to round a number to an integer. The number will be converted to a string first, sometimes with unexpected results:

```
var num = 1000000000000000000000;
parseInt(num) // 1, because the string representation is 1e+21
```

> I got idea while writing this question that Math.floor() might write 5 when it's 4,5 and parseInt() would write 4

You’re thinking of rounding to the nearest whole number, which is what `Math.round` does. `Math.floor` always rounds down.

Comment: Great non-trivial example!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where their behaviour differs drastically: negative numbers.

```
Math.floor(-2.5) -> -3
parseInt(-2.5) -> -2
```

The semantic difference pointed out in other answers, however, is probably more important. Even if it does work for your particular and specific use-case, it's best to pick the one with the correct semantics. (There are countless other ways to return a seemingly random integer from a function, you should pick the one that's the least likely to make your code hard to maintain.)

Comment: Thank you! But would that matter with random number generator? As much as I understand it wouldn't, so basically I could use either one of them and it would be as good, yes?

Comment: @Zyberg just because two solutions give the same result, that doesn't mean they are equally good. Think of maintainability - either when you have to modify the code in the future, or when somebody else has to read it.

Comment: I understand that and in a way it was why I posted this question. Thank you for answering it to such detail!

Answer (score 0):

The clear difference is that `Math.floor` is a function that works on numbers while `parseInt` is a function that takes a string. You don't want to use the latter here as we deal with random *numbers*.

If you are unsure about the rounding mode, compare `Math.floor`, `Math.round` and `Math.ceil`.

Comment: parseInt just converts its first argument to a string, doesn't necessarily expect one ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)). (Altough I do agree using it any other way is probably bad practice)

Comment: @doldt: Yeah, sure, but the point is that we don't want to convert our numbers to strings. We don't do `Math.floor("1.23")` either (altough it works the same and converts its argument to a number).