# Initialize array with variables: Unexpected token +

Tags: javascript, arrays, initialization

I created a simple function which should initialize an array and return one random element from it everytime when the function is called.

```
function test(str)
{
    var myArray = 
    {
        "Test1 "+ str + " Test1",
        "Test2 "+ str+ " Test2"
    }

    return myArray[Math.random()*myArray.length+0];
}

console.log(test("FOO"));
```

But I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +`

Comment: `myArray` is not an array... But `object(key-value pair)`

Comment: `var myArray = 
    [
        "Test1 "+ str + " Test1",
        "Test2 "+ str+ " Test2"
    ]`

Comment: and `+0` is always useless :)

Comment: return myArray[ Math.floor((Math.random() * myArray.length)) ];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in your code `myArray` is not an array,

```
function test(str){
    var myArray = ["Test1 " + str + " Test1","Test2 " + str + " Test2"] 
    return myArray[(Math.random() * myArray.length) | 0];
}
```

`|` This is bit wise OR operator. When doing operand1 | operand2, both the operands will get converted to *base 2* and performs the `OR` operation over it. Finally the result will get converted back to the *base 10*. Hence the decimal points will be removed.

Comment: This is the best solution i think.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Glad to help! :)

Comment: Yes! Nice solution.. Just explain `|` :)

Comment: "*converted to base 2 that is binary*" is confusing, if not wrong. Yes, the number will be converted to a 32 bit integer, but everything on a computer is "binary". And there is no "*original base*", it's a floating point number.

Comment: @Bergi Corrected the things that you said. But base 2 numbers cannot be told as binary? I have a confusion on this.

Comment: Oh, sure "binary" can mean the same as "base 2", just like "decimal" stands for "base 10". But every number on a computer really already is in a binary format - unless it is stored in a string - so this "base conversion" is meaningless. What really happens is a conversion from floating point to integer format, which strips the decimal digits. Or just use `Math.floor`, then you don't have to [explain](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9049677/1048572) [anything](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7487977/1048572).

Answer (score 2):

Use [ ] instead of { } for a JS Array.

```
function test(str)
    {
        var myArray =
                [
                    "Test1 "+ str + " Test1",
                    "Test2 "+ str+ " Test2"
                ]

        return myArray[parseInt(Math.random()*myArray.length, 10)];
    }
```

Comment: @upvoters This will give `undefined` all the time.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Updated to parse double to int.

Comment: Thank you, but i think the solution from @RajaprabhuAravindasamy is easier to understand.

Comment: @EdwardBlack parseInt(str, b) parses str to an integer in base b.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Decimal.

Comment: -1.                                                                                                       [Do not use `parseInt` on numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32039288/1048572)!